# PHP - Assigning Two Values To One Key in Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key

I need to get an array in this format:

```
$arr = {

$domain => $PR => $OBL

}
```

In other words, I want each domain to act as a key which has two values, PR and OBL (pagerank and outbound links) assigned to it. Doing this for only one value is easy, I simply loop through and set: `$arr[$domain] = $PR;`

And then it's easy to extract data via simple for-each loop later. But what's the best way to store two values for each domain and how do I loop through it to extract data later on?

Comment: Post an expected output

Comment: That syntax is invalid. Simply use an array to store `domain` attibutes: `$domain => array($PR, $OBL)`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are running an up to date PHP (5.5.x):

```
$arr = [
  'domain1.tld' => [8, 2543],
  'domain2.tld' => [3, 684],
];
foreach($arr as $domain => list($pr, $obl))
  echo "<p>$domain has PageRank $pr and $obl outbound link(s)</p>";
```

Alternatively, more compatible and more verbose:

```
$arr = [
  'domain1.tld' => ['PR' => 8, 'OBL' => 2543],
  'domain2.tld' => ['PR' => 3, 'OBL' => 684],
];
foreach($arr as $domain => $properties) {
  $pr    = $properties['PR'];
  $obl   = $properties['OBL'];
  echo "<p>$domain has PageRank $pr and $obl outbound link(s)</p>";
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: this is perfectly possible using older versions as well, just with a little less syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yeah in pre-5.4 you'd need to replace the `[...]` declarations with `array(...)`, and the `foreach...list` combo can be replaced with a separate line in between.

Answer (score 2):

Add to Niels Keurentjes` answer:

```
$arr = array(
   'domain1.tld' => array(8, 2543),
   'domain2.tld' => array(3, 684),
);

array_map(
   function ($domain,$values){
      list($pr, $obl) = $values;
        echo "<p>$domain has PageRank $pr and $obl outbound link(s)</p>";
}
,array_keys($arr)
,$arr);
```